# Finding horizontal count of items in an image

Tags: python, image-segmentation

I'm trying to find the count of horizontal columns in an ordered image (a sprite image that is used to generate an animated image):

[image: Sprited dino]

From this image, I'm trying to generate a meta-data file like so:

```
{ 
"frames": 12, 
"cols": 6, 
"width": 102, 
"height": 89
}
```

Frames would be the total count of "elements" in the image, columns is the horizontal column count, and width/height is for the individual "element" and can be calculated, once you know the column count.

## What I Have Already

I've been using numpy/scipy/python mainly since I am a Python guy, but not too experienced with scipy.

[This answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2516/counting-the-number-of-groups-of-1s-in-a-boolean-map-of-numpy-array) showed me how to get the total count of elements in an image and got me this far ipython:

[image: ipython count]

## Where I'm Stuck

On most simple images, the ndimage.label works well, but once the image gets too dense, it seems to fall apart.

I've tried using a kind of line-by-line average of the file: subtract 1 horizontal line, get the ndimage.label count of total elements in the picture, then keeping subtract the whole image to build buckets and calc the average std deviation for the image; which would be the horizontal count. But this still isn't accurate on dense images like this: [image: http://asktherelic.com/priv/npc_bundle_of_joy__x1_talk_png_1354839566.png]

Would anyone have suggestions for a better algorithm or counting method?
Thanks!

For ease of hacking I have a zip with the ipython notebook and sample images available here: http://asktherelic.com/priv/sprite_sample.zip

And it looks something like this currently: 
http://asktherelic.com/priv/sprite_sample.html

Answer (score 1):

Using any image processing library, here is the simple step

1. Threshold invert  with high value will give you each object as a contour.
2. Now process each contour and find centre of mass.
3. Then sort contour by co-ordinates.

Comment: Or just look for vertical lines of empty pixels and count how many of those there are